# Android - cannot scroll up

Tags: java, android, scroll, adapter

First off, I first laid eyes on Java three weeks ago so bear with me if this code is terrible. It's an assignment for school that I am to build on a prototyped app and give it a UI, so the Adapter is basically all I've done to this.

My problem being that as soon as I touch the scroll, I get thrown to the bottom of the list and can't scroll back up without getting pushed back down.

```
/**
 * VaxjoWeather.java
 * Created: May 9, 2010
 * Jonas Lundberg, LnU
 */

package dv106.weather;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * This is a first prototype for a weather app. It is currently 
 * only downloading weather data for Växjo. 
 * 
 * This activity downloads weather data and constructs a WeatherReport,
 * a data structure containing weather data for a number of periods ahead.
 * 
 * The WeatherHandler is a SAX parser for the weather reports 
 * (forecast.xml) produced by www.yr.no. The handler constructs
 * a WeatherReport containing meta data for a given location
 * (e.g. city, country, last updated, next update) and a sequence 
 * of WeatherForecasts.
 * Each WeatherForecast represents a forecast (weather, rain, wind, etc)
 * for a given time period.
 * 
 * The next task is to construct a list based GUI where each row 
 * displays the weather data for a single period.
 * 
 *  
 * @author jlnmsi
 *
 */

public class VaxjoWeather extends ListActivity {
    //private InputStream input;
    private WeatherReport report = null;

    //private ArrayList<WeatherForecast> forecastList = new ArrayList<WeatherForecast>();

    private WeatherAdapter adapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        adapter = new WeatherAdapter(this);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        //getListView().setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_DISABLED);

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.yr.no/sted/Sverige/Kronoberg/V%E4xj%F6/forecast.xml");
            AsyncTask task = new WeatherRetriever().execute(url);
        } catch (IOException ioe ) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void PrintReportToConsole() {
        if (this.report != null) {
            /* Print location meta data */ 
            //System.out.println(report);

            /* Print forecasts */
            int count = 0;
            for (WeatherForecast forecast : report) {
                count++;                
                adapter.add(forecast);
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Weather report has not been loaded.");
        }
        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private class WeatherRetriever extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, WeatherReport> {
        protected WeatherReport doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            try {
                return WeatherHandler.getWeatherReport(urls[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } 
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(WeatherReport result) {
            report = result;
            PrintReportToConsole();
        }
    }

    // custom ArrayAdpater to show, weather icon, temperature, and precipation.
    class WeatherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WeatherForecast> {

        public WeatherAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context,R.layout.forecast);
        }

        @Override   // Called when updating the ListView
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row;
            if (convertView == null) {  // Create new row view object           
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.forecast,parent,false);
            }
            else    // reuse old row view to save time/battery
                row = convertView;

            // TextView for Temperature
            TextView temperature = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.temperature);
            temperature.setText(Integer.toString(this.getItem(position).getTemp())+" °C");

            // TextView for out Precipation.
            TextView precipation = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.rain);
            precipation.setText(String.valueOf(this.getItem(position).getRain())+" mm");

            // Image Icon for forecast.
            ImageView icon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            String iconPath = "ic_";            

            if (this.getItem(position).getWeatherCode() <= 9){
                iconPath = iconPath+"0"+(Integer.toString(this.getItem(position).getWeatherCode()));
            }
            else {
                iconPath = iconPath+(Integer.toString(this.getItem(position).getWeatherCode()));
            }

            int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(iconPath, "drawable", getPackageName());

            // If the resource ID is invalid, as in the image not existing, we'll add the postfix for periods.
            if (resId == 0){

                // Set the icon image source dependent on period code given.
                if(this.getItem(position).getPeriodCode() == 3){
                    iconPath = iconPath +"n";
                }

                else if (this.getItem(position).getPeriodCode() == 2){

                    iconPath = iconPath +"d";
                }
                else {
                    iconPath = iconPath +"m";
                }

                resId = getResources().getIdentifier(iconPath, "drawable", getPackageName());
                icon.setImageResource(resId);
            }
            // Or if everything checked out, we'll just run with the resource ID and find our Icon.
            else {
                icon.setImageResource(resId);
            }

            return row;
        }
    }

}
```

I tried applying another standard arrayadapter and actually got the same unwanted scrolling results, so I got no idea what part it is I got issues with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found and apparently it had nothing to do with my code. Class suggested we'd use Intel x86 instead of ARM for our emulators. Running it with ARM scrolling work just as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Way to do it is:
1: Place ListView in main.xml
2: In your Activity Make object of ListView like so -> private  ListView listView; in onCreate connect it to the main.xml like this, listView = (ListView) R.id.listView1; // whatever it is called

3: next create an ArrayList:-> private ArrayList arrayWeather = new ArrayList();

4: fill the arraylist with weather data then finally create object of class you created and make it use your arraylist to display data.

Example:
    public class ListUser extends BaseAdapter{

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arraylistData.size(); // the arraylist u created
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arraylistData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arraylistData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(v == null){
            LayoutInflater lf = (LayoutInflater) BuyPets.this.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = lf.inflate(R.layout.forecast, null);
        }


        // setup here, done


        return v;
    }

}
```